# Not able to show the data on html Page by using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am Beginner to Angular ,using Angular 1.0 to do Crud Operation, am able to Add the data into database(sql server 2008) ,want to show the data on Partial Page ListPlayer.html but i am not getting the data -Got stuck at the Point ,So many changes in Angular been there ,please help me on this

This is My app.js File Code

```
var app = angular.module("ApplicationAngularDemo", ["ApplicationAngularDemo.controllers", "ngRoute"])

app.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when("/", { templateUrl: "/Partials/PlayerList.html", controller: "MainController" }).

        when("/AddPlayer", {templateUrl:"/Partials/AddPlayer.html",
        controller: "AddPlayerController"
        }).
        when("/EditPlayer/:id", {
            templateUrl: "/Partials/EditPlayer.html",
        controller:"EditPlayerController"}).
    otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });

}])
```

This is my controller.js File

```
angular.module("ApplicationAngularDemo.controllers",[]).
controller("MainController", function ($scope ,PlayerService) {
    $scope.message = "Main Controller";
    PlayerService.GetPlayersFromDB().then(function (response)
    {
        $scope.listPlayers = response.data.list; 
    })

}).
    controller("AddPlayerController", function ($scope, PlayerService) {
        $scope.message = "Add Player Details";

        $scope.AddPlayer = function ()
        {
            PlayerService.AddPlayer($scope.player);
        }



    }).controller("EditPlayerController", function ($scope)
    {
        $scope.message="Edit Player Details"

    }).

factory("PlayerService", ["$http", function ($http) {

    var fac = {};
    fac.GetPlayersFromDB = function ()
    {

        $http.get("/Player/GetAllPlayers");
    }

    fac.GetPlayerById = function (id) {

        $http.get("/Player/GetlPlayerById", { params: {id:id}});
    }

    fac.AddPlayer = function (player) {

        $http.post("/Player/AddPlayer", player).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data)
                alert('Data Submitted Successfully');
        })
    }

    fac.UpdatePlayer = function (player) {

        $http.post("/Player/UpdatePlayer", player).then(function (response) {
            if(response.data)
            alert('Data Updated Successfully');
        })
    }



    fac.DeletePlayer = function (id) {

        $http.post("/Player/DeletePlayer", { id: id }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data)
            alert('Data Deleted Successfully');
        })
    }


    return fac;

}])
```

This is My player controller class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Entity;
using ApplicationAngularDemo.Models;

namespace ApplicationAngularDemo.Controllers
{
    public class PlayerController : Controller
    {
        private CrudContext _context = null;


        public PlayerController()
        {

            _context = new CrudContext();
        }

        public JsonResult GetAllPlayers()
        {
            List<Player> listPlayer = _context.Players.ToList();
            return Json(new { list = listPlayer },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public JsonResult GetlPlayerById(int id)
        {
            Player Player = _context.Players.Where(x => x.PlayerId == id).SingleOrDefault();
            return Json(new { player = Player }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


        public JsonResult AddPlayer(Player player)
        {
            _context.Players.Add(player);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { status = "Player Added Successfully" });
        }

        public JsonResult UpdatePlayer(Player player)
        {
            _context.Entry(player).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { status = "Player Updated Successfully" });
        }

        public JsonResult DeletePlayer(int id)
        {
            Player Player = _context.Players.Where(x => x.PlayerId == id).SingleOrDefault();
            _context.Players.Remove(Player);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { status = "Player Deleted Successfully" });

        }




    }
```

}

This is My Partilal ListPlayer where i am using ng-repeat direactive

```
<h3>List Of Players</h3>
{{message}}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Club</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="player in listPlayers">
        <td>{{player.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{player.Club}}</td>
        <td>{{player.Country}}</td>
        <td>{{player.Age}}</td>



    </tr>


</table>
```

& This is the deafult Page ApplicationAngularDemo.html where i am rendering this Partilal Views (Page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Angular Demo App</title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>   
    <script src="Scripts/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ApplicationAngularDemo">
    <div  ng-view>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: data is loading into the list (GetAllPlayer method) but on response i want to show it on the Page which is not happening

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing here is you are not returning from your service. Your service function should look something like this:

```
fac.GetPlayersFromDB = function () {
    return $http.get("/Player/GetAllPlayers");
}
```

And so on for other functions that get data from the API as well.

That should fix it!

Comment: thnx @tanmay -So silly mistakes i did ,thnks for help

Comment: @SarveshGujrati please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it helped